# Modifying existing Alfresco Content Model

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, content-model

We would like to insert a class between two Alfresco class sys:base and cm:person. What are the options? Like type Party has 2 children, Person(individual) and Organisation, So how to model it as Type Party comes between sys:base and cm:person.

Answer (score 4):

That's bad practice! You should not modify Alfresco's default content model.
Take a look at Aspects - you should be able to create a new aspect & add your aspect to your cm:person nodes

Comment: Yes, default content model should not be modified, but is there any other way, other than aspects?